# How do I inject a dependency into non Controller classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor

I want to do some setting up of my application (initialisation). I do this in `Global.asax.cs`.

I'm going to need a dependency (perhaps a repository) to achieve my goal.

**How do I inject an implementation of `IFooRepository`?**

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{

    private static IFooRepository _fooRepository;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // ...

        IFoo foo = _fooRepository.Get(0);
        foo.DoSomething();
    }

}
```

I tried this but it failed:

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    void IWindsorInstaller.Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container,
        Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(
            Component.For<IFoo>()
            .ImplementedBy<Foo>()
            .LifestyleTransient(),
            Component.For<IFooRepository>().AsFactory());

        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IFooRepository>()
            .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

**How do I inject dependencies into something that isn't constructed (a static class)?**

I've read through the [documentation for interface-based factories](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx) but I don't understand it.

**What are facilities? What are they used for?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `MvcApplication` is the class that would typically trigger the initialization of the application and registration of all components, you can't let the DI container inject dependencies into it. Besides that, containers have no built-in support of injecting static dependencies, since in the context of Dependency Injection, the usefulness of injecting statics is fairly limited.

But the solution is actually quite simple: you should resolve the `IFooRepository` from the container after you're done configuring it.

Note though that you should only store that `IFooRepository` in a static field when you registered it as singleton. Otherwise you will (accidentally) promote that `IFooRepository` to singleton, which might cause all kinds of trouble (such as concurrency conflicts, or caching problems).

Comment: What if my Dependency Resolution (Castle Windsor) is in another project and I don't have access to it from my UI?

Comment: That's an unlikely situation. The configuration of your container must be triggered from the startup path of the application (a.k.a. the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/)) and with MVC this startup path is your `MvcApplication`.

Comment: That's my situation :\ Is what I want possible?

Comment: Either you get a reference to the container and ask the container for an instance, or you add a `GetFooRepository()` method in the library where the container is used and call it from within your `MvcApplication`.

Comment: +1 and accepting because it answers the question and is insightful.